# Frameworks like facebook six waves giving error apportable

Tags: objective-c, apportable

i have an existing project in which im using multiple frameworks. Xcode compiles it fine but when apportable load compiles it, its giving a lot of errors

```
>> error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScaleTo' 
>> error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenuItemToggle' 
>> error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCFadeTo' –
>> '#import "CJSONDeserializer.h" not found 
>> NSRegularExpressionSearch uncdeclared 
>> ushort undeclared etc
```

there are lots of errors like these please help

```
/Users/Tashfeeen/Desktop/Development/IosKoH/Classes/Platform/MafiaFarmAppDelegate.h:12:9: 

fatal error: 
  'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`
```

Comment: Better specify who/what/where is the problem occurring

Comment: i have an existing project in which im using multiple frameworks. Xcode compiles it fine but when apportable load compiles it, its giving a lot of errors like one i have mentioned above and few following

#import "CJSONDeserializer.h" not found
NSRegularExpressionSearch uncdeclared
ushort undeclared etc

there are lots of errors like these please help

Comment: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScaleTo'
error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenuItemToggle'
 error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCFadeTo'

Comment: Great! now edit your post with the proper data and hope fop the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the undefined references, it seems the project isnt being picked up for cocos2d's targets. This can commonly be caused by variations of having many sub-target projects. You can check in your .approj/targets if there is a cocos2d target in there you can add to your .approj/configuration.json

```
"modules": [
    {
        "project": "MyProject", 
        "build_cwd": "./", 
        "target": "cocos2d library", 
        "project_config": "Release"
    }
],
```

If this target is not available, you can manually add the cocos2d files into the .approj/configuration.json under the add_params section

```
"sources" : [
    "libs/cocos2d/Platforms/Mac/CCDirectorMac.m",
    "libs/cocos2d/Platforms/Mac/CCEventDispatcher.m",
    ...
]
```

Currently we do not yet have NSRegularExpressionSearch enabled in the public SDK, usually these can be just changed to standard string searching. Supporting this unfortunately means that we have to package icu4c which can add a fair amount of binary size to the application; we are working to reduce that to a reasonable level so that we can package it in all builds.

Per the Facebook headers, it seems you are likely using the binary Facebook framework, which will not work without the Indie version. That being said, you can compile the Facebook SDK from source if it is included in your project as a sub-project.